# ProgrammingError while trying to insert data into a MySQL table using Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Although I am quite new to SQL I have already used python to build DBs, but now I am stuck.

To put it simple, I have a schema with three tables, which are related to one another via foreign keys. They were created using python, as described below (not showing the definitions of `c` and `conn`, as I am pretty sure that the error does not lie there):

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

# create the runsMaster table
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ngsRunStats_FK`.`runsMaster` (
    `run_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `run_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`run_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB""")

# Create the samplesMaster table
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ngsRunStats_FK`.`samplesMaster` (
  `sample_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run_ID` INT NULL,
  `sample_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sample_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_table1_runsMaster1_idx` (`run_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_runsMaster1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`run_ID`)
    REFERENCES `ngsRunStats_FK`.`runsMaster` (`run_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB""")

# Create the XYStats table
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ngsRunStats_FK`.`XYstats` (
  `XYstats_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `run_ID` INT NULL,
  `sample_ID` INT NULL,
  `X_TOTAL_COVERAGE` FLOAT NULL,
  `X_TARGET_COUNT` FLOAT NULL,
  `X_MEAN_TARGET_COVERAGE` FLOAT NULL,
  `Y_TOTAL_COVERAGE` FLOAT NULL,
  `Y_TARGET_COUNT` FLOAT NULL,
  `Y_MEAN_TARGET_COVERAGE` FLOAT NULL,
  `Ymeancov_Xmeancov` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`XYstats_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_XYstats_runsMaster_idx` (`run_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_XYstats_samplesMaster1_idx` (`sample_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_XYstats_runsMaster`
    FOREIGN KEY (`run_ID`)
    REFERENCES `ngsRunStats_FK`.`runsMaster` (`run_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_XYstats_samplesMaster1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sample_ID`)
    REFERENCES `ngsRunStats_FK`.`samplesMaster` (`sample_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB""")
```

Both the `samplesMaster` and the `runsMaster` table are working fine. They are automatically populated from other iterations that are not all that important for the understanding of this problem.

After a few operations, I want to extract some values from a pandas df (`XY_df`) and insert into the `XYStats` table. My pandas df looks like the following

```
                   0              1     2           3
0                  X  121424.000000  64.0  1897.26000
1                  Y      14.019900   4.0     3.50497
2  Ymeancov/Xmeancov       0.001847   NaN         NaN
```

Below is the dictionary that can be obtained from the table with `XY_df.to_dict()`

```
{0: {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Ymeancov/Xmeancov'},
 1: {0: 121424.0, 1: 14.0199, 2: 0.00184739},
 2: {0: 64.0, 1: 4.0, 2: nan},
 3: {0: 1897.26, 1: 3.5049699999999997, 2: nan}}
```

The code that I am using to populate the `XYStats` table is shown below:

```
c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO XYstats (run_ID, sample_ID, X_TOTAL_COVERAGE, X_TARGET_COUNT, X_MEAN_TARGET_COVERAGE, Y_TOTAL_COVERAGE, Y_TARGET_COUNT, Y_MEAN_TARGET_COVERAGE, Ymeancov_Xmeancov)
VALUES
('{runID}', 
'{sampleID}',
'{XY_df.iloc[0,1]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[0,2]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[0,3]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[1,1]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[1,2]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[1,3]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[2,1]}'
""")
conn.commit()
```

But then I get

```
ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11
```

Which is not informative at all I reckon

I am quite sure that my error **does not** lie in

1. The tables creation. I have been using the `runsMaster` as well as the `samplesMaster` the way they are
2. The data type that I am trying to insert into the `XYStats` table> `XY_df` is a pandas data frame and what I am trying to insert (e.g. `XY_df.iloc[0,3]`) are `numpy.float64` (`type(XY_df.iloc[0,1])`)

But other than that I am quite clueless on what's going on as the error message that I am getting is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a syntax error in the query you are executing on SQL. You have an unclosed bracket after VALUES. All you need to do is add a closing bracket at the end of the query string and you're good to go:

```
c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO XYstats (run_ID, sample_ID, X_TOTAL_COVERAGE, X_TARGET_COUNT, X_MEAN_TARGET_COVERAGE, Y_TOTAL_COVERAGE, Y_TARGET_COUNT, Y_MEAN_TARGET_COVERAGE, Ymeancov_Xmeancov)
VALUES
('{runID}', 
'{sampleID}',
'{XY_df.iloc[0,1]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[0,2]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[0,3]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[1,1]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[1,2]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[1,3]}',
'{XY_df.iloc[2,1]}')
""")
```

Comment: There you go, I swear up and down that I was paying attention the commas, but I apparently I neglected the closing brackets after `VALUES`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! As a piece of additional advice, generally injecting data values from another source directly into SQL query strings like this is bad practice due to it introducing [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I'm not sure what SQL connection library you are using, but look up whether it supports **parameterized queries** and try using those instead.